# Drive name lost! missing `server' JVM at `*:\Software\JRE\bin\server\jvm.dll'

Tags: java

as you see in the title, my java home is "D:\Software\JDK" and "D:\Software\JRE"(Window 10 17134.81, Java 8e172).

But now the drive name has been changed from 'D' to '*' and when you excute "java" in cmd it return a error message like this:

> Error: missing `server' JVM at `*:\Software\JRE\bin\server\jvm.dll'.
>   Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing
>   components.

How can I get it back to normal?

PS: I have installed the latest java10 and it return to normal. But I still want to know how to fix this issue without reinstall.

Comment: As the message suggests - reinstall!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time look into windows registry under key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` and around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Registry under this key is all wrong. I searched all "*: \Software\JDK" and "*:\Software\JRE", then changed it to correct drive name D. It return back to normal!